# Returning the values of an 'ndarray' using an array of indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tuples

I am trying to get the values of an `ndarray` using an array of indices.

Suppose `a` is the target array and `b` is the array of indices. Then:

```
a = np.asarray([[[1,2,3]],[[2,3,4]],[[3,4,5]]])
b = np.asarray([[0,0,1],[0,0,2]])
print a[tuple(map(tuple, b))]
```

Should return what I want but I get `Index Out Of Bound Error'.

The output I expect is:

```
[2,3]
```

Comment: You have a syntactical error in the initialization of `b`, and it's not clear what `coord` is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you want `a[tuple(b.T)]`.  Making the numbers unique to make it easier to verify:

```
>>> a = np.arange(9).reshape(3,1,3)
>>> b = np.asarray([[1,0,2],[2,0,0]])
>>> a
array([[[0, 1, 2]],

       [[3, 4, 5]],

       [[6, 7, 8]]])
>>> b
array([[1, 0, 2],
       [2, 0, 0]])
>>> a[1,0,2]
5
>>> a[2,0,0]
6
>>> a[tuple(b.T)]
array([5, 6])
```